# Navbar Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm a starter on Bootsrap and I have a little problem with my navbar, I looked everywere but didn't see anything... Here is my problem

When you click on the right button "Français", it's display a sub menu with a bold line on the toP and the bottom !

Here is the link
http://www.deluxe-art.fr/question/index.html

Here is my CSS

```html
body      {font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#fff;}
.header-top     {padding:15px 0; background-color:#000; border-bottom:#ff821d solid 3px; color:#fff!important; box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)!important;}
.navbar-collapse   {border:0!important; box-shadow:none!important;}
.header-top a    {color:#fff!important; font-weight:700;}

/*Links*/
.navbar-nav > li > a  {color:#fff;
       -webkit-transition: color .5s ease-in;
       -moz-transition: color .1s ease-in;
       -o-transition: color .1s ease-in;
       transition: color .1s ease-in;}
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {color:#ff821d!important;}
.navbar-nav > .active a  {color:#ff821d!important; background:transparent!important;}
.navbar-toggle    {background-color:#000; color:#ff821d!important; border:none;}
.navbar-toggle:hover  {background-color:#000!important; color:#ff821d!important;}
.icon-bar     {color:#ff821d!important;}
.dropdown a     {font-weight:300!important;}

.dropdown-menu > li > a  {background-color:#000!important; border:none;}

.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {color:#ff821d!important; background-color:none; border:none;}
.navbar-brand    {margin-top:-13px!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your submenu without the *bold lines* (padding of the `<ul>`) on top and bottom:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Note that every dropdown menu you use has padding 0px, so it is better to make a own class and put it behind the **class** dropdown-menu

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu myMenu">
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

in your HTML.

```
.myMenu {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```